# uploading files to google drive api using python

Tags: python, google-api, drive

I am trying to upload two text files to google drive using python.
Below is code where i am getting exceptions,I am using v2 version of drive api.

```
FILES = (('textDoc1' , False),('textDoc2' , True))
for filename, convert in FILES:
    metadata = {'title' : filename}
    res = service.files().insert(convert=convert,body=metadata,media_body=filename,fields='mimeType,exportLinks').execute()
    if res:
        print('Uploaded "%s" (%s)' % (filename,res['mimeType']))
```

Error getting is

```
C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Python Classes>python quickstart.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "quickstart.py", line 78, in <module>
main()
File "quickstart.py", line 67, in main
        res=service.files().insert(convert=convert,body=metadata,media_body=filename,fields='text').execute()
```

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 802, in method
    raise UnknownFileType(media_filename)
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownFileType: textDoc1

Comment: mimetypes.add_type("application/vnd.android.package-archive", ".apk")

Comment: @Crt where to add this piece of code in discovery.py? Can you elaborate here ?

Comment: have you tried just including it in the code you posted above? before the ```for``` loop

Comment: NameError: "global name 'mimetypes' is not defined"
I think it should be added at system level ?

Comment: @AshishBainade mimetypes is a standard module. do import mimetypes

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked:)

```
FILES = ['textDoc1','textDoc2','textDoc3','textDoc4','textDoc5','textDoc6' ]
for filename in FILES:
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename + '.txt', mimetype='text/plain')
    body = {'title': filename}
    print (filename)

    res = service.files().insert(media_body=media, body=body).execute()
    if res:
        print('Uploaded "%s" (%s)' % (filename,res['mimeType']))
```